# Current page to PDF jQuery / PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, pdf

I know that there are several libraries available in PHP for outputting HTML content into a PDF file, however my case is a little more complex.

We have a series of invoices which contain user input data, and then several `input` elements whose content is calculated and output using jQuery and vanilla JavaScript.

I am looking for a soluiton whereby once the current page has completed loading, and all calculations have finished, the page is then converted to PDF, including the values created by jQuery inside `<input disabled="disabled" />` elements.

Does anyone know of a suitable library to output the contents of the page to a PDF file?

Here's the kind of flow I have in mind:

1. Loading HTML page in Browser
2. Present user with 'download file' dialogue
3. Save PDF file to user's machine
4. Close HTML page.

Comment: Send the form's data to the host as an AJAX request or something, generate the PDF on the host, then stream it back to the client as a downloadable PDF file.

Comment: I believe it is bad idea to convert client-side-generated invoice to PDF, as it will enable the malicious customer to generate fake invoices. Just generate all HTML serverside at once and send the client the resulting PDF.